# Action Bar Sherlock and some stupid exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, actionbarsherlock-map

I just started to use action bar and tab navigation. App is running good, but i have problems when the phone goes to sleep, i wake it up, and i go to the next tab I get this exception and i don't know where to look. Exception is:

```
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:6326)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:6310)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.restoreActionViewStates(MenuBuilder.java:361)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.preparePanel(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:503)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:272)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:150)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:156)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1100)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-07 11:16:57.026: E/AndroidRuntime(20228):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I'm missing the statement 'caused by' in your logcat. Is this all?

Comment: This is all...this confuse me to...

Comment: First thing, it is stupid, not stuppid.. :-) Second thing, [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/652) bug reported in their github page looks similar, and they tell about a fix.. Might help you..

Comment: :D Mistake..forgive me, but english is not my mother language! :) Yes it look like that this is the problem. I just asked how to fix it.

Comment: I found a fix that is not implemented in sherlock library. If you post you answer i will check it as true! :) Thanks man..

Comment: @Jovan if you found a different fix from the one mentioned in the link, then it is better you post it as answer yourself because that is the answer worked for you. And that might be the answer that works for future visitors. If the fix you found is present in the above link, then I can post it as answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a bug in ActionBarSherlock implementation. See discussion about the bug [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/652). 
And someone uploaded a patch [here](https://github.com/ChrisSmith/ActionBarSherlock/commit/c5f968c1a136a940a722f2cfc2a8ef0850de4a69). Check if that works for you.